# How to scale an embedded flash video and not crop it?

Tags: html, flash, browser, resize, embedded-video

I have embedded a flash video on my website.

I am having the problem that it seems to rescale fine in Firefox on the Mac, but in Firefox in Windows it just crops the video.

Here it my HTML

```
<object width="650" height="500">
<param name="movie" value="How To Add A Location">
<embed src="http://www.fribblesoft.com/zs-content/How_To_Add_A_Location.swf" 
 width="650" 
 height="500" 
 allowfullscreen="true" 
 bgcolor="#000000" 
 scale="tofit" 
 type="application/x-shockwave-flash" 
 pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer">
</embed>
</object>
```

Comment: Looks like it might have something to do with, http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/141/tn_14149.html or http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/127/tn_12701.html, but still no luck figuring it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is going to be with the Flash, not the HTML. The movie is scaled correctly when it first loads, but after a few seconds it changes dimensions. This indicates that the Flash is probably resizing all of the elements dynamically based upon pixel values, rather than relative to the size of the stage.

Answer (score 1):

I think this just might be a property of the Jing video.  The following html seems to work for other shockwave files.

```
<object classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" 
        codebase="http://fpdownload.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=8,0,0,0" 
        width="100%" 
        height="100%">
<param name="movie" value="How_To_Add_A_Location.swf" />
<param name="quality" value="high" />
<param name="scale" value="exactfit" />
<embed src="How_To_Add_A_Location.swf" quality="best" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="100%" height="100%" allowfullscreen="true" scale="exactfit" pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer" />
</object>
```